# Can't update. I have some cache issue message

Tags: updates

I Receive that message when I try to update. Not connected to the Wi-Fi.

[image: 1]

Comment: You have PPA that doesn't match your Ubuntu version. See here for solutions: https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file

Comment: What is your version of Ubuntu?